# How can Room generate a class with the exact same name as my RoomDatabase class?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-room

To use Room, we create an abstract class that extends `RoomDatabase` and use a builder to get an instance of it.

```
@Database(entities = {Note.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class NoteDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

  private static NoteDatabase instance;

  public abstract NoteDao noteDao();

  public static synchronized NoteDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
      if (instance == null) {
          instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                  NoteDatabase.class, "note_database")
                  .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                  .addCallback(roomCallback)
                  .build();
      }
      return instance;
  }
```

I understand that Room generates the implementation for this class, but how is it possible that I get an instance of `NoteDatabase` if it is declared abstract? Shouldn't it have a different name?

Comment: You don't.  You get an instance of a subclass of NoteDatabase.  Anyplace you have a variable of type X, you can have a variable of type Y if it extends type X.

Comment: @GabeSechan or an anonymous instance.

Comment: Ah right, I had a logical error. Thank you!